# form validation not working in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, codeigniter-3

I'm not able to run the form validation in CodeIgniter. It is not returning any errors or any submission to the database.

**When i'm using**

`$this->form_validation->set_rules('subemail', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');`

My code gets executed but not in below case. Why?

**Controller name Form_sub :**

```
class Form_sub extends CI_Controller {

        public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        #loading model
                $this->load->model('form_model');
                $this->load->helper(array("form",'url'));
     }#EOF CONSTRUCTOR

    public function index(){
        $this->load->view('form.php');
    }//default page
    public function subscribe(){
            echo "hello1"; 
            $config = array(
                    'field' => 'email',
                    'label' => 'email id',
                    'rules' => 'required|max_length[50]|min_length[5]|valid_email|trim|htmlspecialchars',
                    'errors'=>[
                        'required' => '* You must provide an %s',
                        'max_length' => '* %s should be of maximum 50 characters',
                        'min_length' => '* %s should be of minimum 5 characters',
                        'valid_email' => '* You must provide a valid %s'

                    ]
                )

            $this->form_validation->set_rules($config);
            echo "hello2"; 

            if($this->form_validation->run() == false){
              $this->load->view('form.php');
              echo "hello3"; 

            }
```

**View name form.php :**

```
<div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
              <?php echo form_open('form_sub/subscribe'); ?>
                <input name="email" id="" type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('email');?>" class="normal" placeholder="Email Address">

                   <?php echo form_error('email'); ?>     
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 button">
<!--                <input type="submit" id="subsubmit" name="send" class="button" value="Subscribe">-->
                  <input type="submit" class="button" value="Subscribe">
                <?php echo form_close(); ?>
              </div>
            </div>
```

**Model name form_model :**

```
class form_model extends CI_Model {
    public function __construct() {
         parent::__construct();

    }


        public function subscribe_insert($data)
                {
            if($this->db->insert('subscribe',$data))
                    {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                echo "something went wrong in the database";
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: Remove those `echo` statements (hello1 and hello2). You need to check one case at time and `if than else` block is good place for something like that. Capitalize model class name. File should be `Form_model.php` and class should be `Form_model`. Before that enable error reporting and set displaying errors in `index.php` file.

Comment: You are not showing all of your code... Your Form_sub Controller is missing the end bits.... Where are you calling $this->form_model->subscribe_insert($data); ?

Comment: Read and follow the examples in the documentation before diving into your project.